# Printing output to file

Tags: python

i have a dict as below. I want the output to be directed to a file say 'insert.sql'. I am trying to print the result set here. and I need help with sending this output to a file. So far this is the code i have written. What am I missing here.

Expected Output:

```
insert into abc values (
'india',
'china'
);
```

Observed output:

```
insert into abc values (
'china'
);
```

Code:

```
newdict = {'asia': 'india',
           'asia': 'china'}

print("insert into abc values (")
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(newdict.items()):
    if i:
        print(",")
    print("'" + v + "'", end="")
print("\n);")
```

Comment: dictionaries have unique keys. print `newdict` after creating it and you will see that only the last value for the `"asia"` key will be available. One alternative is to use a list to store the various countries, and use only unique keys. Then accordingly write the logic for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
with open('insert.sql', 'w') as output:
    print("insert into abc values (", file=output)
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(newdict.items()):
        if i:
            print(", ", file=output)
        print("'" + v + "'", end="", file=output)
    print("\n);", file=output)
```

`print`'s `file` argument allows you to pass file, to which print's output will be written instead of default standard output.

EDIT: since you're using only values you can use somewhat shorter version:

```
for i, v in enumerate(newdict.values()):
```

Comment: File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print("'" + v + "'", end="", file=output)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @Ritesh are you opening the file in `wb` mode?

Comment: No, it's my bad habbit, fixed as well.

Comment: the output in the file only prints china.! why is that ? duplicate keys not allowed right !!

Comment: i replaced wb with b and i was able to get the output

Comment: Your `if` statement doesn't need to be there. `if i` will fail when `i=0`

Comment: You've `if i:` condition, which removes first entry in `newdict`. EDIT: fixed to add `","` before every, but first entry.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are creating a dictionary and duplicating a key in it which effectively creates a dictionary with the last value as the value for the key,

```
>>> {'a': 10, 'a': 20}
{'a': 20}
```

(which is just like doing:

```
>>> data = {'a': 10}
>>> data['a'] = 20
>>> data
{'a': 20}
```

In your case I think you would need to use a list of values for each key, i.e.

```
>>> data = {'asia': ['india', 'china']}
>>> for continent, countries in data.items():
...     for country in countries:
...         print(continent, country)
... 
asia india
asia china
```

BTW, there is no need to use `enumerate` and check whether ther is an index as the `for` loop will terminate if there is no element

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same key in the dictionary so 'india' is replaced by 'china'. Try to make it into a list.

```
newdict = {'asia': ['india', 'china']}

print("insert into abc values (")
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(newdict.items()):    
    for j, country in enumerate(v):
        print("'" + country + "'", end="")
        if j!=(len(v)-1):
            print(",")
print("\n);")
```